# PHP rename image based on HTML form input file ID

Tags: php

I was wondering whether it is possible to rename an image base on the form input file ID.

```
<form action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input id="picture_01"  type="file">
    <input id="picture_02"  type="file">
    <input id="picture_03"  type="file">
    <input id="picture_04"  type="file">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want that if the image is uploaded from input 4 it will be renamed to 'picture_04', if it is from input form 2 it will be renamed to 'picture_02'. Not sequencially but according to the input form box.

I haven't managed to do this despite the various trial and errors.

Comment: What have you tried?  When you save the file server-side, you can set the name to any value you want.  Setting it to the form element where you read it should be easy enough.

Comment: Can we get the PHP code you're using and the final result you're expecting to see?

Comment: This should be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509333/php-how-to-upload-save-files-with-desired-name

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your inputs:

```
<input id="picture_01" name="picture_01" type="file">
```

etc.

Then in PHP you retrieve the image with the `$_FILES` array, like `$_FILES['picture_01']` or by simply looping through `$_FILES`.

```
foreach( $_FILES as $input_name=>$file)
{
  // $input_name is the name used as the form input name
  // $file is an array with the following keys: name, type, tmp_name, error, size.
}
```

Of course the manual is always a good read http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 0):

I would use separate forms for each input. This way you could use a hidden input like:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <input type='hidden' name='picture_03_file' value="picture_03" />
   <input type='file'   name='picture_03_name' />
</form>
<form action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <input type='hidden' name='picture_04_file' />
   <input type='file'   name='picture_04_name' value="picture_04" />
</form>
```

This way your PHP code would look like:

```
$imgName = $_POST['picture_04_name'];
// Do file upload here
```

Comment: Thanks but i think its too messy

Comment: You don't need that. The `$_FILES` array already has the names as keys. Just loop through it.

Comment: The file names as keys, or the input names as keys?