# How to store data?

Tags: php, excel

I have a client which wants to run an application on localhost on his intranet. 
He has accounts for which he has made folders for each client like
for

```
directory/harry
directory/Rohan
```

and when any user has to do work,they work in their folder only like 
rohan will work in `directory/harry` etc and what they do is they make files excel files.

Now my client wants an automated system in whenever a user makes an excel file, then there should be a popup or some way in which he writes what work is done (description) and save that data along with the username and time in a text file in the same folder.

Any body can tell me a way to do this?
Language to be used is php. 
I just need ideas and logic by which this can be done.

Comment: The application you talk about is also written in PHP? And it is this application that produces the Excel files?

Comment: Application is what i'll be making in php with these consideration in mind ......and these folders are outside wamp on local machine.

Comment: Your needs requires other languages/tools other than PHP. Restricting folders by user depends on your OS. You can create a command that checks folders and detect changes in Excel files and you can use a queue driver but I don't recommend it. If your client use Windows, give .net a change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll create an login/user administration to handle with the users, studying [HASH](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) to handle with passwords effectively, using a DB to store those users (I advise you [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/)) and studying [Session](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php) to know how to maintain those users logged in.

After that, when a admin or user sign up, create a folder with their name into directory/username (it's better to use [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to maintain the dirs in a some kind of pattern) without them see (backend only) and redirect the user to the upload form, which will contains an textarea to fill the description of the work done and an input file to store the excel file in. When the user clicks on submit, store the textarea description in the DB, along with the username toke by Session ($_SESSION['username'] can be) and the current data using NOW() into DB insert query. After that, if the insert was a success, move [that file to a directory using some functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509333/how-to-upload-save-files-with-desired-name#3509388).

I advise you to create a table to view all information filled by the user, filtering only the user's interactions if the user status is normal and bringing all the infos stored in database if the user is admin using SELECT into your db and creating your frontend in html.

PS: Remember to put enctype="multipart/form-data" into your form, you will work with files inside a form, [it's necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean).

[multipart/form-data](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4)

The content "multipart/form-data" follows the rules of all multipart MIME data streams as outlined in [RFC2045]. The definition of "multipart/form-data" is available at the [IANA] registry.

A "multipart/form-data" message contains a series of parts, each representing a successful control. The parts are sent to the processing agent in the same order the corresponding controls appear in the document stream. Part boundaries should not occur in any of the data; how this is done lies outside the scope of this specification.