# PHP insert form data and upload file to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file-upload

I am trying to create a form that inserts user data into a database table and upload a file however I can't figure out how to add the file to a database. The form data enters no problem just not the file. Any help would be appreciated.

PHP Form:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="frm_add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" value="add" name="action" id="action">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="medID" class="control-label">ID</label>
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="medID" name="medID"/> 
              </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                <label for="emp_id" class="control-label">Employee No:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp_id" name="emp_id"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Full Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"/>
              </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title" class="control-label">Job Title:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title"/>
              </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="documents" class="control-label">Supporting Documents:</label>
        <input type="file" name="documents" class="form-control">
              </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>          
</form>
```

insert.php

```
    <?php
    //include connection file 
    include_once("connection2.php");

    $db = new dbObj();
    $connString =  $db->getConnstring();

    $params = $_REQUEST;

    $action = isset($params['action']) != '' ? $params['action'] : '';
    $empCls = new Student($connString);

    switch($action) {
     case 'add':
        $empCls->insertStudent($params);
     break;
     case 'edit':
        $empCls->updateStudent($params);
     break;
     case 'delete':
        $empCls->deleteStudent($params);
     break;
     default:
     $empCls->getStudents($params);
     return;
    }

    class Student {
    protected $conn;
    protected $data = array();
    function __construct($connString) {
        $this->conn = $connString;
    }

    public function getStudents($params) {

        $this->data = $this->getRecords($params);

        echo json_encode($this->data);
    }
    function insertStudent($params) {
        $data = array();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `employee` (emp_id, name, title, documents) VALUES('" . $params["emp_id"] . "', '" . $params["name"] . "','" . $params["title"] . "', '" . $params["documents"] . "');  "; 
echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("error to insert student data");
}
```

What am I doing wrong, what do I need to add to documents? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please read about [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead of building queries with string concatenation, use [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). See [**this page**](https://phptherightway.com/#databases) and [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for some good examples.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` that covers GET and POST arrays, not FILES. Having error reporting enabled, would have thrown you an undefined index. You need to do a bit of a rewrite here.

Comment: Hi Talha. In the web you can investigate a lot of examples to how to manage uploaded files with php. Here you can view one: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Storing files at DB is not very common. If you really want to do it, you can use blob fields. But you can store them in filesystem or in a external storage system.

Comment: @Curlas Please avoid linking to w3schools. It's very low-quality content and is often full of serious security holes and terrible advice. Whenever possible link to the [official manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php), or a higher-quality tutorial or explainer otherwise.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Answer (score 1):

It's pointless to save a file inside the database. Get the file name only, nothing else

```
$info = pathinfo($_FILES['userFile']['name']);
$ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
$newname = "newname.".$ext; 

$target = 'images/'.$newname;
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'], $target);
```

The code above is from here : [How to upload & Save Files with Desired name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509333/how-to-upload-save-files-with-desired-name)

So what you need to do is save the name in your database and than just access that name with the path to that file that holds said "Name"

Comment: you are right, but you can also save the file to db by converting to to `blob` format, also you need to set the datatype of the `table column to blob`

Comment: Thank you for that information, so the $target is the folder path where it stores the file and only adds the name to the database? I have tried that but it's not actually adding anything to the database and I am guessing the problem is with my INSERT section: what do I change the document value too? currently, it is '" . $params["documents"] . "'

Comment: @TalhaS Debug your form with die(); before the insert method and print out your $_POST see if something is missing there , if nothing is missing than the issues is in the INSERT method

Comment: The form is entering all the data into the database but it is still not entering the file name or uploading the file to the folder.